# Vb.net - error after converting website to solution '<name> is ambiguous because multiple kinds of members with this name exist in <type> '

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I converted by vb.net website into multiple project solution. But after creating that I am getting many errors in each `aspx` file and `vb` file. Below screenshot for reference.

[image]

I have multiple labels or buttons with same name in multiple file but in vb file its not referring to current file and getting error like `<name> is ambiguous because multiple kind of members with the same name exist in class.`

Comment: Posting images of code is unacceptable on SO.

Comment: You'll have to compare the converted code with the original code to determine what needs to be changed. There's nothing anyone here can help you with from what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

> I converted by vb.net website into multiple project solution.

Hum, that's quite a bit to digest here.

It not clear if you has a asp.net web site, and you are converting that asp.net web site into a asp.net web site "application".

You would most certainly do the above step BEFORE you THEN start to introduce multiple projects into "one web site appliation".

So, without question one great reason and benefit to convert a asp.net web site into a asp.net web site application is those types of projects allow multiple projects into one project.

However, that 2nd goal and step of multiple projects?

You can't go down that road until such time you had a successful conversion to a web site application first. Then and ONLY then do you want the 2nd step of introduction of multiple projects into one project.

so, at the start of this whole change over, I would assume you FIRST obtained a working asp.net web site application, and THEN you can start down the road of introduction of multiple projects into one project. However, you would not do nor attempt this 2nd step of multiple projects UNTILL such time you have the asp.net web site working as a asp.net web site "application".

As pointed out, I VERY much doubt a simple post here with what you provided is going to allow anyone here to help you more then you who enjoys the ability to be sitting on that computer with the those projects. I not sure what is worse, you thinking that with the information that's been provided that we can help with such limited information, or that you skipped some steps here (but then again, we don't know what you done so far for converting the web site into a web site application, and maybe you done that already? (but, we have no clue and don't know).

in fact, maybe you already have a web site application? Again, we don't know.

I can only suggest and state that you most certainly will convert the web site into a working "application" BEFORE you start introduction of multiple sites into that one project.